# How to find the offset of a field of a struct?

Tags: memory, rust, struct

I have a Rust struct `C` having a field `f`. The struct is serialized (as a vector of bytes that we can get from `C` by `transmute`) in an external storage that is a finite sequence of bytes (e.g. a file) in position `a`.

I need to find the position `af` under which the field `f` is serialized.

Equivalently, I need to find the offset of the field `f` in the struct.

How to do it in standard Rust?

Comment: You can use [`std::ptr::addr_of!((*a).f)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ptr/macro.addr_of.html) to get a pointer `af` from the pointer `a`.

Comment: @PitaJ `a` is not a pointer, it is position in e.g. a file. `a` may be unaligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a constant context, you can construct a dummy value and extract the byte offset from that:

```rust
#[repr(C)]
struct C {
    b: u8,
    f: u16,
}

impl C {
    const OFFSET_f: usize = {
        let c = C {
            b: 0,
            f: 0,
        };

        // cast to u8 pointers so we get offset in bytes
        let c_u8_ptr = &c as *const C as *const u8;
        let f_u8_ptr = &c.f as *const u16 as *const u8;

        unsafe { f_u8_ptr.offset_from(c_u8_ptr) as usize }
    };
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(C::OFFSET_f); // [src/main.rs:25] C::OFFSET_f = 2
}
```

And here's an alternative version that doesn't require manually creating a dummy value:

```rust
impl C {
    const OFFSET_f: usize = unsafe {
        let c = std::mem::MaybeUninit::uninit();
        let c_ptr: *const C = c.as_ptr();

        // cast to u8 pointers so we get offset in bytes
        let c_u8_ptr = c_ptr as *const u8;
        let f_u8_ptr = std::ptr::addr_of!((*c_ptr).f) as *const u8;

        f_u8_ptr.offset_from(c_u8_ptr) as usize
    };
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `repr(C)`?

Comment: You should try reducing the scope of `unsafe`, in the second example, to better highlight which operations -- exactly -- are unsafe. There are only two unsafe operations here: `offset_from`, and `*c_ptr`, and both should be accompanied with a `//  Safety` comment explaining why they are sound. (I believe `*c_ptr` is sound as it matches `addr_of_mut` examples, but I am not 100% convinced)

Comment: There's the `memoffsetof` crate that encapsulates that logic.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Given this runs at compile time, any soundness issues will be caught by the interpreter anyways.

Comment: @porton field order of rust structs is not guaranteed - the compiler is allowed to put them in any order for optimization. `repr(C)` tells the compiler to always use the C layout for the given structure, guaranteeing stability.

Comment: @PitaJ: Is there an actual guarantee that the interpreter uncovers all soundness issues? I know it's the case in C++ with regard to UB, but I'm not sure whether the same commitment was made for Rust.

Comment: @PitaJ So, the order of fields may change when I switch to a new version of Rust compiler and I need `repr(C)` to avoid such changes? I'd also like my structures to be packed. Can I have both `repr(C)` and packed? or how to do this?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I found crate `offset` but not `memoffsetof`.

Comment: @porton My problem, it is `memoffset`. I don't know if the `offset` crate is sound.

Comment: @porton yes. You'll want to use `#[repr(C, packed)]` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

We can use package [offset](https://crates.io/crates/offset).

The syntax is `offset_of!(Type::field)` where `Type` is either an ident or a path in angle brackets.